# Mandatory order fields in Craft Commerce 2

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

Ist it possible to add validation rules for Carts/Orders? I need to check whether there is at least one list item added to the cart before payment is initiated.

Unlike addresses (*Address::EVENT_REGISTER_ADDRESS_VALIDATION_RULES*) there seems not to be an event for manipulating rules.

I’d prefer a server-side solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting for this specific instance `allowEmptyCartOnCheckout`.

Creating a `commerce.php` file in the `config` directory with the following code will prevent customers from checkout out with an empty cart.

```
<?php

return [
  'allowEmptyCartOnCheckout' => false
];
```